# MySQL Data Load is only loading in about half the rows in my table

Tags: mysql, file-io, load, line

I'm loading in a table with over 500k rows.  It worked multiple times before, but now has seemingly stopped working. Code is as follows:

```
load data local infile 'C:\\Users\\Michael\\Dropbox\\Coursework and Work\\Project Longevity\\NHPD DB\\Arrests Working Files\\ARRESTS_REDO2.csv' into table all_arrests
fields terminated by ','
enclosed by '\"'
lines terminated by '\n'
ignore 1 lines
(object_id, id_key,case_num, seq_no, arrest_date, arrest_time, arrest_hour, arrest_week, arrest_month1, arrest_month2, arrest_type, arrest_type_info,
charge_seq, statute, counts, arresting_officer, arresting_officer2, perp_name, perp_sex, perp_sex_info, perp_race, perp_race_info, perp_ethnicity, perp_ethnicity_info, 
red_num, perp_dob, perp_age, beat, district, arrestee_community, street_number, street_direction, street_name, street_suffix, street_direction2, street_name2, 
street_suffix2, street_apt, street_city, v_community, v_street_num, v_street_direction, v_street_name, v_street_suffix, v_street_direction2, 
v_street_name2, v_street_suffix2, v_street_apt, v_city, h_street_number, h_street_direction, h_street_name, h_street_suffix, h_street_apt, h_city, h_state,
h_zip, cv_dayofweek, cv_address, cv_date, cv_dow, cv_time, status, score, side)
;
```

I have tried changing the line end parameter to \r and \t per other threads, but no dice.  It loads, and the data that IS in there is good, but it only is loading 256218 rows out of what should be 512271.

Comment: Look around line 256218 in your data.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check:

- If timeout is smaller than the time consumed by query if you are using a client like MySQL Testbench
- Your file have a row with special character or a mismatch that its making the reading break